# How to schedule my android app to do something every hour

Tags: java, android, schedule, alarm, alarmmanager

I want my app to access database every hour and read next record from the table then update desctop widget and send notification. I know that there is AlarmManager which I can use to register my Intents but they are deleted when the phone is turned off or rebooted.

Is there any other android class/service that I would update my application continuously even when I reboot my phone?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a look at the demo applications provided with android sdk

http://developer.android.com/samples/RepeatingAlarm/index.html

the look at AlarmService_Service for the implementation of the service once the alarm has been triggered

Comment: With respect to "but they are deleted when the phone is turned off or rebooted", you need to implement a `BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver to re-establish your alarms after a reboot. If you are implementing an app widget, you also have the option of using `android:updatePeriodMillis` in your app widget metadata -- this alarm is automatically managed for you, but it is not as flexible.

Comment: The example does not seem to be available online any longer, and is obviously also not available with newer SDK versions. However, a similar (maybe even the same?) example can be found here: https://code.google.com/p/android-lab/source/browse/trunk/android-lab/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmService.java

Answer (score 2):

put all of the background tasks you want to do in your app in `Services` which perform tasks in the background. In the service you should be able to define a timer that causes whatever updates you want to occur every x hours.

In the `onCreate()` of the widget, start the service. `onCreate()` is called every time that the widget comes to life (such as when the phone starts if it is on the home screen) and will therefore guarantee that the `Service` is always running.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Having an everlasting service is a one-way ticket to a one-star rating on the Market.

Comment: no, i never said an "ever lasting service" was a good idea, but @marqss said he wanted a service that was always running... even after the phone was reset.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of completness, I am linking here the official docs, where the issue of the rebooting is adressed.

http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#boot