# Keep Service Alive which Starts from Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android

I have a major Issue,

I make a Broadcast receiver which apply on the Device boot up, so i need to start a new service for performing long-running operation,

So in the onReceive() method of Broadcast Receiver I make a new Intent and by this Start a new service,

Now my problem is that this Service executes only for short time, as soon as the onRecieve() method finish it process is also finished and my Service is also stops with the finishing of Receiver process.

So how I can do this, to keep alive the Process of Service which starts from the BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: I'm not sure if this matters but are you using a separate thread for your service?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696082/how-to-schedule-my-android-app-to-do-something-every-hour

Follow the two links and try out the example.

Comment: No not use the separate thread, but in the Service I use the Separate Thread, but this thread is also stopped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now my problem is that this Service executes only for short time, as soon as the onRecieve() method finish it process is also finished and my Service is also stops with the finishing of Receiver process.

That would only occur if you are calling `stopService()`, or the service is calling `stopSelf()`. The service has an independent lifecycle from the `BroadcastReceiver`. It will not even be *started* before `onReceive()` ends.

> but in the Service I use the Separate Thread, but this thread is also stopped.

That will only occur if you are stopping the thread yourself. Android does not know about threads you create.

Now, eventually, your app's process will be terminated. With a running service, this could take anywhere from 30 minutes to a couple of days, depending on what else is all going on with the device, whether you are using `startForeground()`, etc. Once the process is terminated, everything goes away, background thread and all.

Comment: But Then why this service terminates, If I call the startService() inside the activity then it not terminates

Comment: can you please give me a code for start activity from BroadcastReceiver or Service class, I use the following code but error comes.      Intent i=new Intent(this,MyActivity.class);
  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  startActivity(i);     Error is the Flag error, it says cant start activity without activity context

Comment: please give me a reply I really need this

Comment: So even when using Service, there is a chance that Android will kill it without user intervention? If so, how does the other apps work if they have some running instructions in the background for a long time?